# Is there an automated way to convert files from .pv to .log?

Tags: purify, rational-purify

Is there a way to convert a .pv file to a text file apart from opening each one with purify -view and then exporting it?

I have lots of .pv generated files from running lots of tests with my executable instrumented with Rational's Purify. I know that I can specify -log-file=logfilename.log to generate the text version of the output when I run the tests. But I have thousands of tests and don't want to update them all to change the -log-file parameter used.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a script job.  You iterate all your .pv files and export the log-file using purify.  In bash this would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.pv; do
  purify -view $f -log-file=$f.log -windows=no;
done
```